# How can I install a missing locale?

Tags: localization, 3.2-honeycomb, samsung-galaxy-tab-7.7

I bought Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.7 in Hong Kong. The System has some pre-installed languages but I need to install an additional locale (Polish). I tried "More Locales 2" from the Market and it worked but not as I expected. Some text is fully translated, but others are not. Is there any way to localize it correctly? Polish locales are supported by Android 3.2 but I do not know how to install them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should install the European version of Samsung's ROM or any other ROM of choice. [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1469635) lists official firmwares for your device.

Comment: Honestly, I was thinking that some easier solutions are available. Anyway, many thanks for your answer. I need to read more about this whole ROM stuff. I will wait a while with marking your answer as accepted, maybe someone else show up here.